# Return CString Array from MFC c++ dll to C# program

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll, c-strings

I am developing a MFC Dll that will be used by a c# UI program. Using MFC classes i get CString Array from a function. I need to send that Array to my C# UI program. C# does not recognize the CString types, so i tried to covert Cstring to char* and then make a char* Array to send the Array to CString. I used the following convertion method to convert CString to char*.

```
CT2A temp(CStringArray[i]);
```

But this makes the String some mixed up,unreadable characters, when received in c# program.

I checked if i create and send char* Array, without using any converted CString, All data are okay in the Array. But i need to pass the CString Array data. Is there any other approach to this? or How can I return a CString Array from MFC c++ dll to C# program.

Comment: What does your existing function look like that returns CStringArray? It would help to see what your current code looks like - enough to offer suggestions.

Comment: Also, why convert to ANSI in this day and age? You should stick with Unicode implementations. Win9x fell out of support long ago, so there's really no reason to use ANSI unless you're interacting with old legacy systems. Define `UNICODE` in your precompiled header and just use Unicode everywhere. Makes everything so much easier. Like marshaling unmanaged memory to .NET. It's going to be much easier to marshal unmanaged memory if you don't have to worry about codepages at the same time.

Comment: Let's be inventive. On the C++ side,  create one giant string from the 2D array, where each entry in the 2D array would be delimited by some means (comma, pipe character, etc).  Then the problem becomes a simple sending / receiving a string, not an array of strings.  The C# code would have to parse the string, but that should be easy to do.

Comment: BTW, the technique of using a delimited string in lieu of an array of strings is how the Windows standard file dialog's [OPENFILENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea) structure sets up the filtered list of files.  So all of the time you use an app that shows the "File Open" dialog, that combo box of all the different file types to save is set up in a similar manner (the strings are delimited by a null, and terminated with a double null byte).

Comment: @Heath This is a sample scenario.

        CString someCString = _T("Some Cstring");
 CT2A temp(someCString);
 char* charString = "ABC";
 static char* myArray[3] = { temp, charString, "CC3"};
 return myArray;

When i get myArray in C# the value of index 1 and 2 are read correctly, but the value in index 0 becomes unreadable characters. In actual scenario values of myArray all will be some CString.

Comment: In c++ the delimiter is '\0' for a string and last string in the array will have "\0\0".  Also in c# the string is one byte (not unicode) so you return byte[] from c#.  Then it is a simple loop to extract the array using '\0' as the delimiter and the entire array will end when you return an string that is empty (only a '\0').

Comment: @jdweng do not use byte[] for strings. The marshaller supports strings - ANSI or Unicode - just fine.

Comment: @Jamiul I actually need to see more of how your function is defined (is it a class method? A global function? Is the name exported? Is it decorated? Please update your question to be more helpful. I have countless lines of P/Invoke and COM interop since before .NET 1.0 was released. But knowing what the function looks like you're trying to call in managed code is vital to giving you a suggestion.

Comment: Also, .NET can marshal arrays of strings just fine as well. But I wouldn't recommend marshalling a CStringArray directly unless you can get a pointer to its backing LPTSTR* - assuming that's how CStringArray even stores strings. If it doesn't say, don't assume. It becomes an implementation detail that could change. If they document it, it *should* remain stable. Even delimiting the string and marshalling it that way will have issues because it uses more memory and you have to parse out \0 in managed code. This can be done with at most count * sizeof(TCHAR) allocated memory.

Comment: @Heath : Where did I say the Marsh did not handle the array of string.  I simple said what must be done in c++ to send back the array of strings which is the title of the posting.

Comment: "Also in c# the string is one byte (not unicode) so you return byte[] from c#." Strings in .NET are all Unicode. Always. You can marshal them as ANSI or Unicode to/from native code. You typically use string (for in) or StringBuilder (for out) - never byte. Why make it harder than it has to be on either side of P/Invoke? Most times, even the defaults (no properties set on DllImportAttribute) work fine.